# Animation not running when called from other view controller

Tags: ios

I have the a sidebar in my `ipad` app and when there is this method toggleMenu which is performing the animation but when i call the method from another view controller it does not perform animation . The method runs fine but no animation

The method is

```
-(IBAction)toggleMenu
{

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Menu Slide" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

if(self.contentView.frame.origin.x == 0) //Menu is hidden
{

    NSLog(@"show menu");

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(self.contentView.frame, self.menuView.frame.size.width, 0.0);
    self.contentView.frame = newFrame;

}
else //Menu is shown
{

    NSLog(@"hide menu");

    [menuTableView reloadData];
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(self.contentView.frame, -(self.menuView.frame.size.width), 0.0);
    self.contentView.frame = newFrame;

}

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: you are calling an animation on a viewcontroller that is not visible and wonder why you don't see it?

Comment: " toggleMenu " Is it a Method or an IBAction ? . I mean , are U calling it or clicking from UI..

Comment: its an IBAction @KumarKl and

Comment: Can U show your code  " when called from other view controller" ?

Comment: slidemenu = [[slidemenuviewcontroller alloc]init];
[slidemenu togglemenu];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You have to send notification from another view controller when you want to animate ..

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"animationstart"        object:nil];
```

in slidemenuviewcontroller

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad

{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(toggleMenu) name:@"animationstart" object:nil];

}

- (IBAction)toggleMenu
{
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"Menu Slide" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

if(self.contentView.frame.origin.x == 0) //Menu is hidden
{

NSLog(@"show menu");

CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(self.contentView.frame, self.menuView.frame.size.width, 0.0);
self.contentView.frame = newFrame;

 }
 else //Menu is shown
 {

NSLog(@"hide menu");

[menuTableView reloadData];
CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(self.contentView.frame, -   (self.menuView.frame.size.width), 0.0);
self.contentView.frame = newFrame;

}

[UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

Comment: Mann i dont have word to thank you .. u r a gem ... thanks a lot

Comment: i dont have enough points to set your comment as answer but as soon as i get i will surely do